# Artifactory Maven example fails with 401 error code

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm trying Artifactory on my localhost. Even though I've followed their [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGXrPz9wwOY)
to do their 
[Maven example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/maven-example), I fail with 401 status code. Here is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project multi: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.test:multi:pom:3.7-20190117.083916-1 from/to snapshots (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer file http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/org/jfrog/test/multi/3.7-SNAPSHOT/multi-3.7-20190117.083916-1.pom with status code 401 -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project multi: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.test:multi:pom:3.7-20190117.083916-1 from/to snapshots (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer file http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/org/jfrog/test/multi/3.7-SNAPSHOT/multi-3.7-20190117.083916-1.pom with status code 401
```

Here is content of settings.xml located  in /Users/my_user_name/.m2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP84FzVbdvwcgreF8m9HT77ESkA"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP84FzVbdvwcgreF8m9HT77ESkA"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And I've added this to pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>0e5e20a55438-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Error code 401 hints me authentication issue. I'm wondering how does settings.xml resolve credentials, e.g. `${security.getCurrentUsername()}`? I even put plain username and password in the settings.xml ,but still it failed.

Can you please tell me what's wrong in my settings and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: which version of artifactory are you using?

Comment: I use Aritfactory based on Docker, on my mac. I use this Docker image:  docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

Comment: sorry, which version of artifactory (?); it tells you when you open the UI, in the bottom left corner

Comment: Artifactory Version 6.6.5

Comment: Did you download the settings.xml file as shown in the video, or copy/pasted it?

Comment: yes, I did. And for confirmation, I copy pasted the content. I did exact same as tutorial. FYI, I'm running Aritfactory on my mac, I don't know fi this has any effect.

Comment: That's the problem, you are not supposed to copy/paste the settings.xml; please check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOTE: there is [a bug](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory6.5.2) in artifactory 6.5.x, which was resolved in version 6.5.2, that prevents filtered resource to be correctly processed.

`${security.getCurrentUsername()}` is an usage of a [filtered resource](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Filtered+Resources), which in artifactory allows to treat text files as filtered via FreeMarker templates.

When you download the `settings.xml` file in the artifactory UI, the `${security.[]}` fields would have been replaced with your currently logged username and encrypted password (*if* that bug was not present). Because of the bug, or *if* you copy/paste the text content instead of downloading, the settings.xml will contain those literal unreplaced strings, and maven would not replace them because they do not exist in the maven build context.

As shown in the video you linked, you need to click the `download snippet` link, instead of copying the text; otherwise, you can copy/paste the text and then you need to type your artifactory username and password in it.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem. However I should say that even by downloading settings.xml, still this issue exists and user should manually replace the credentials.

Comment: Downloading the settings as admin preserves the template without populating it so you could use the template as [a filtered resource](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Filtered+Resources) as needed. Downloading it as any other user will filter the tokens.

Comment: On artifactory OSS 6.16.0 rev 61600900, I still have the field "half" populated (as in the original post).
User is not an admin, but logged in with LDAP. No Admin right, downloading the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have landed here and are getting a 401 when trying to use artefactory cloud, for me the issue was I added a the public mirrors section (this wasn't added by the `Generate Maven Settings` link:

[image: Artefactory Set Me Up Dialog]

This gave me a section in the settings.xml of:

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>public</name>
      <url>https://{my-domain}.jfrog.io/artifactory/public</url>
      <id>public</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors
```

As I was therefore using this mirror I needed to add in further authentication in to the servers section:

```
       <server>
          <username>{username}</username>
          <password>{encrypted password}</password>
          <id>public</id>
      </server
```